# Getting error from akka dispatch

Tags: scala, akka, scala-dispatch

I want to implement an async rest via scala dispatch but i get an error, and i don't know why.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

```
11:    import dispatch._


  def sendRestTo(s: String, body: Option[String] = None) = {

47:         val request = host(s)
  }
```

Compiler:

[error] file.scala:11: not found: object dispatch

[error] import dispatch._

[error] file.scala:47: not found: value host

[error]     val request = host(s)

[error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine helped me out, 
thx to anyone who gave it a thought.

The problem was, that my intelliJ had the library dependencies in its build.sbt, but not imported.

---

> **"net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core"         % "0.11.2",**

---

I just imported the lib, and the problem was solved.